# Free function is terribly slow in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, performance, codeblocks, free

So I'm on ubuntu 64bit and I'm using CodeBlocks with GNU GCC compiler. The problematic part of my code is basically this

```
int testFunction() {
  int i;
  char* test[10];

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
          test[i] = malloc(50*(sizeof(char)));
  }

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    free(test[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Without freeing everything that is malloc'd run time is 2s and with free part it is 20s atm. Any ideas why?

Comment: What kind of an ancient machine would it take so that the first loop runs in 2 *seconds*?

Comment: I think you are measuring something else.

Comment: this gets called thousands of times every time program is ran

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: While I agree with the above comments that the time you are measuring is ridiculously slow, I can reproduce the fact that calling `free` makes the function much, much slower in [ideone](http://ideone.com/kJgxCQ), where commenting out the `free` gets a time of ~1*10^(-7) s, whereas leaving it in gets a time of ~6*10^(-6) seconds, for a full order of magnitude difference.

Comment: @mikerson You should have mentioned that at the first place. So OK, `free` is slow (actually no, it is not *slow*, it is *slower* than `malloc`, that's all). Probably it is implemented using some sophisticated algorithm for memory management. If you want to know exactly, look at it's implementation.

Comment: Are you mesuring a debug build ?

Comment: How is that supposed to be related to the IDE?? It is a matter of the standard library/OS/whatever provides the functions. And without a [mcve] as @MichaelWalz already asked for, it is impossible to provide a qualified answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can measure your time to be sure.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <bits/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i;
    char *test[10];
    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        test[i] = malloc(50 * (sizeof(char)));
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("time malloc %f\n", time_spent);
    begin = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        free(test[i]);
    }
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("time free %f\n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
time malloc 0.000046
time free 0.000003
```

You can try the program [online](http://ideone.com/Q4DNqV).